# Datatable breaks when adding indexes to JSON array

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json, datatable

I have a datatable which populates from a php array converted to JSON array and everything works fine when I'm just pulling fields from my database as is, but I wanted to add some calculated fields as the last few columns so I did them in php here:

```
foreach ($in as $id){
    $query = $link->prepare("SELECT provider_num, provider_name, 233_net_charity_care, 291_cost_of_non_mcr_bad_debts, 301_cost_of_uncomp_care
                FROM `s10`
                            WHERE `id` = :id");
    $query->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->execute();
    $results = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if($results['301_cost_of_uncomp_care'] != 0){
                $charityPortion = ($results['233_net_charity_care'] / $results['301_cost_of_uncomp_care']);
                $baddebtPortion = ($results['291_cost_of_non_mcr_bad_debts'] / $results['301_cost_of_uncomp_care']);
                } else {
                    $charityPortion = 0;
                    $baddebtPortion = 0;
                }
    $data[] = $results;
    /*$data['charityPortion'] = $charityPortion;
    $data['baddebtPortion'] = $baddebtPortion;*/
}
```

which then turns into a json variable to be passed into the datatables init `var tableData = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>;`

and then I initialize datables with the json:

```
$('#compTab').dataTable({
        "aaData": tableData,                               
        "aoColumns": [
            { "data": "provider_num" },
            { "data": "provider_name" },
            { "data": "233_net_charity_care" },
            { "data": "291_cost_of_non_mcr_bad_debts" },
            { "data": "301_cost_of_uncomp_care" }
            /*{ "data": "charityPortion"},
            { "data": "baddebtPortion"}*/
        ]
    });
```

Currently I have these last 2 columns commented out as every time I add them to my data array, datatables reports that no data was found, even though the values show up in the right place when I echo the JSON.

My question is this: Is there something I am missing with these two variables which causes datatables to trip up? I had a feeling I might be passing them as objects somehow but I think that is covered by `json_encode()`

Any insight on this would be great.

Thanks in advance

Comment: shouldn't be indices `charityPortion` and `baddebtPortion` must be inside `$result` instead of `$data`

Comment: @Ghost is it possible to add indices to the $result variable/array after the fact or do I need to go back and create those indices in my actual database?

Comment: yes you could already do that inside the PHP before the encoding happens, just a simple assignment would do it. assign the inidices inside `$result` first, then finally append in `$data`, doing the other way messes up the array structure, you do not need to add another column

Comment: @Ghost I tried `$results['charityPortion'] = $charityPortion;` and unfortunately when I encoded it to json the field did not exist. Is my syntax correct? I did some research and it looks like I can use 'render:' in my datatables init to do the calculation but obviously I am more comfortable with doing it in php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not calculate charityPortion and baddebtPortion directly in the SQL string? Then, it will be part of $results:

```
SELECT  provider_num, provider_name, 233_net_charity_care, 
        291_cost_of_non_mcr_bad_debts, 301_cost_of_uncomp_care,
        if('301_cost_of_uncomp_care' != 0, 
            ('233_net_charity_care' / '301_cost_of_uncomp_care'), 0) As charityPortion,
        if('301_cost_of_uncomp_care' != 0, 
            ('291_cost_of_non_mcr_bad_debts' / '301_cost_of_uncomp_care'),0) As baddebtPortion
FROM `s10`
WHERE `id` = :id
```

Comment: I honestly had no idea you could do that and that's exactly what I need. Thank you. Question: Is the `, 0` the else equals part of my statement?